# Function return in branches of an `if` vs outside the `if`, in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, return

Are there differences in the compiled code between

```
double func(bool x) {
  if (x) {
    return 1.0;
  } else {
    return 2.0;
  };
}
```

and

```
double func(bool x){
  if (x) {
    return 1.0;
  };
  return 2.0;
}
```

Are there performance reasons to favor one over the other?

The only thing I know is that the second faster to type.

---

I have been using g++, but would be interesting to learn what happens in others, if it is different.

Comment: To improve readability, remove `;` after `}`.

Comment: Well you could compile it and look at the assembly to find out.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't know how that works. Is it easy?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Also consider `return x ? 1.0 : 2.0;`.

Comment: @myfirsttime1 using [gcc.godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) its as easy as copying the code into the editor.  [example](http://goo.gl/bHYlYS)

Comment: @NathanOliver, it's easy to produce assembly. I imagine, OP wants to know if it is easy to understand it. Here YMMV.

Comment: I used clang to get the llvm representation, and both generate identical IR, which means that it would compile to the same assembly.

Comment: @SergeyA You don't have to understand it to see it is the same which is what the OP wants to know.

Comment: Without floating points (int for instace) the assembly it's easier to understant http://goo.gl/7Kqvwq Interestingly, the optimized version doesn't even have branches

Comment: If you're using the `gcc/g++` compiler, you can compile with the `-S` flag to create assembly files, and compare them as you would with text files to see if the two versions give the same machine code. I suppose similar flags exist for other compilers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no performance differences here, because once the compiler takes the "then" branch, the "else" branch becomes unreachable. The code generated by an optimizing compiler should be identical.

The readability of your example does not change, either. However, when the `else` branch is very long and the "then" branch is very short, the second snippet reads better, because it has lower level of nesting.

The situation when "then" branch is short and "else" branch is long is very common - this happens when you perform argument checking, and throw an exception or provide an early termination in case an argument is out of range. The advantages of the second approach become even more pronounced when you consider multiple validations at the top of your function, e.g.

```
if (!arg1.isInRange()) {
    return FAILURE_REASON_1;
} else {
    if (!arg2.isInRange()) {
        return FAILURE_REASON_2;
    } else {
        if (!arg3.isInRange()) {
            return FAILURE_REASON_3;
        } else {
            ... // Payload code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

vs.

```
if (!arg1.isInRange()) {
    return FAILURE_REASON_1;
}
if (!arg2.isInRange()) {
    return FAILURE_REASON_2;
}
if (!arg3.isInRange()) {
    return FAILURE_REASON_3;
}
... // Payload code goes here
```

Comment: yep. Indentation is the only factor to consider, and it's important.

Comment: Another thing to consider is if you have many branches in an if-else-if-else-if -else situation, by putting the returns in each block, you will get a compiler error if you accidentally forget one path.  If you have a blanket return at the bottom, you won't get that error.

Answer (score 1):

"Are there differences in the compiled code between" is a bad beginning anyway. The assembly output is unspecified by the C++ standard except that it has to reflect the rules declared in the standard. With or without one million no-ops in between every instruction - in most cases it's equally conformant. Therefore, using the standard as a reference, you cannot say anything about the actual assembly output because it's dependent on the actual compiler used.
For questions regarding, you need to specify the compiler & version, the OS, the architecture, etc. Otherwise, just compile and compare the assembly output yourself.

Anyway, to address your actual question, the output shouldn't differ on a decent compiler.

---

On my x86-64 machine with GCC 5.2.0:

First:

```
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
   6:   88 45 fc                mov    %al,-0x4(%rbp)
   9:   80 7d fc 00             cmpb   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
   d:   74 0a                   je     19 <_Z5func0b+0x19>
   f:   f2 0f 10 05 00 00 00    movsd  0x0(%rip),%xmm0
  16:   00 
  17:   eb 08                   jmp    21 <_Z5func0b+0x21>
  19:   f2 0f 10 05 00 00 00    movsd  0x0(%rip),%xmm0
  20:   00 
  21:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  22:   c3                      retq
```

Second:

```
  23:   55                      push   %rbp
  24:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  27:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
  29:   88 45 fc                mov    %al,-0x4(%rbp)
  2c:   80 7d fc 00             cmpb   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
  30:   74 0a                   je     3c <_Z5func1b+0x19>
  32:   f2 0f 10 05 00 00 00    movsd  0x0(%rip),%xmm0
  39:   00 
  3a:   eb 08                   jmp    44 <_Z5func1b+0x21>
  3c:   f2 0f 10 05 00 00 00    movsd  0x0(%rip),%xmm0
  43:   00 
  44:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  45:   c3                      retq
```

Don't differ.

Comment: Strange answer. It assumes, there is no reason to write efficient code, since compiler 'can include one million noops'.

Comment: @SergeyA Rewritten. Better?

Answer (score 1):

For starters there is no need to include an empty statement

```
double func(bool x) {
  if (x) {
    return 1.0;
  } else {
    return 2.0;
  };
  ^^^
}
```

As for the question then the compiler can generate the same object code for both functions.

But as for me I would prefer the following function :)

```
double func( bool x ) { return x ? 1.0 : 2.0; }
```

and I do not exclude that the compiler can generate the same object code as for the first two functions from your post.

Moreover it itself can make the functions inline.

So the only question that can exist relative to these functions is which one is more readable.

As for the functions you showed the more readable is the first compared with the second provided that there are no other statements in the functions. Reading the code of the second function I would spend some time to answer the question for myself why there is not used the `else`.:)